# Lex file doesn't recognize keywords. How can I write my regex to read particular keywords?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

This is my lex file

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h> 
    int codelines = 0;
    int commentlines = 0;
    int blanklines = 0;
    int headerlines = 0;
    int brackets = 0;
    int keywords = 0;

    
%}

%%
int|return|char {keywords++}
^[ \t]*\n {blanklines++;}
[ a-zA-Z0-9();]+ {codelines++;}
\{|\} {brackets++;}
#[a-zA-Z0-9<>.]+ {headerlines++;}
\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9 *=]* {commentlines++;}
%%

int main(void) {
    yylex();

    printf("\n");
    printf("Number of Code Lines %d\n", codelines);
    printf("Number of Comment Lines %d\n", commentlines);
    printf("Number of Blank Lines %d\n", blanklines);
    printf("Number of Header Lines %d\n", headerlines);
    printf("Number of Braces %d\n", brackets);
    printf("Number of Keywords %d\n", keywords);
}
```

Here is the input file I'm passing to

```
#include<stdio.h>
                                                                                                                                        
int main() {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    //My name is Witcher
    //Analyzer
    return 0;
}
```

The output is coming like this which is wrong because none of the keywords is detected

```
Number of Code Lines 8
Number of Comment Lines 2
Number of Blank Lines 0
Number of Header Lines 1
Number of Braces 2
Number of Keywords 0
```

It should be something like this with the keywords

```
Number of Code Lines 8
Number of Comment Lines 2
Number of Blank Lines 0
Number of Header Lines 1
Number of Braces 2
Number of Keywords 5
```

I've tried debugging by adding different statements when keywords should be recognized, but the statement is not run at all

Comment: What is the input leading to your output?

Comment: Can you share your input and expected output?

Comment: also flex is greedy so codeLines is going to match even though int is earlier.  and you are not taking into account white spaces which separate the keywords;

Comment: missing semicolon?

Comment: @pmg no it's because of they way OP is eating white spaces that is skipping over keywords

Comment: Added the input file I'm passing and the expected output

Comment: So... you want the same line (eg `"    return 0;\n"`) to count both as "code line" and "keyword line"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is that lex has 2 important properties here:

1. Lex only matches a word once. So if two different regex are able to match the same word, what is going to happen is that lex is going to choose one of the regex to match, and the other one is not. So the question is, which regex is going to match?
2. To choose which regex is going to match a word, lex always choose the longest possible rule.

Ex: Defining 2 keywords: 
`<= {printf("Less equal");}`
`< {printf("Less");}`
And giving the input as `a<=b`. The output would be `Less equal` since `<=` is a longer match then simple `<`
In your code, the codelines regex is matching the words that you want to be matched by keywords regex. As `int main(void)`  is a valid matching word for codelines regex for example.
You should try to rewrite the codelines regex